# Don't number first frame with allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer, numbering, allowframebreaks

Is it possible to remove the numbering on the first slide in Beamer when using the `allowframebreaks` option? Or, alternatively, to number only if there are in fact more than one slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start the numbering from the second slide, you could do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
    \ifnum\insertcontinuationcount>1
    \insertcontinuationcount
    \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{allowframebreaks title}
frame 1
\framebreak

frame 2
\framebreak

frame 3
\framebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\insertcontinuationcount]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{allowframebreaks title}
frame 1
\framebreak

frame 2
\framebreak

frame 3
\framebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn it on also for the first slide, but only use numbering if there are more than one slides?

Comment: @clel Please use the "Ask Question" button on the top right to ask a new question including a minimal working example. This will make it easier to understand what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @clel Are you maybe looking for `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[singleframecheck]`?

Comment: It has been included in the original question, that's why I commented. But I am also happy to create a new question. I'll look into your suggestion and check!

Comment: @clel It is not good if a question includes more than one different questions - this makes it hard for the duplicate mechanism to work. I therefore focus only on the primary question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Looks like your answer is correct, many thanks! Do you want me to create a question for that? Then you can post your answer there and I'll accept it!

Comment: @clel A new question would certainly be helpful for future users with the same problem.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689394/dont-number-first-frame-of-beamer-with-allowframebreaks-when-there-is-only-on here's the corresponding question.