# Don't number first frame of beamer with `allowframebreaks` when there is only one frame (no frame breack needed)

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

Coming from [Don't number first frame with allowframebreaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426832/dont-number-first-frame-with-allowframebreaks), I wondered, whether it is also possible to not display a number for frame breaks *only* when there are no frame breaks required.

That way, the frame behaves like a normal frame when no frame break is needed and numbering will be used only when frame breaks occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beamer v3.64 or newer, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[singleframecheck]` which will only insert the continuation count if the frame has more than one page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[singleframecheck]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{allowframebreaks title}
frame 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{allowframebreaks title}
frame 1
\framebreak

frame 2
\framebreak

frame 3
\framebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```